# If I have an object which is the combination of two shape like a rod going through a sphere. Can I just add the moment of inertia of the two objects?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia

Can moment of inertia of complex shapes found by adding the moment of inertia of its components?

For example
The above mentioned rod through a sphere.

Can I just find the moment of inertia of the sphere and the rod and add the both together

I have seen videos where they add up all the constituent particles using integration. But in all of them I have seen, they only add once with same equations for moment of inertia like adding up rings to get a sphere or discs to get a solid cylinder.

Answer (score 2):

As the definition, $I=\sum m r^2$, shows, you may add the moments of inertia (about the same axis) of the interpenetrating objects. But you must subtract the moment of inertia of the part of the penetrated object that has been replaced by part of the penetrating object!